# Updating a big XML using Talend with StAX module

Tags: xml, oracle, talend, stax

I'm trying to create a Talend job, to update a big XML (11 million Lines, 300 Mb).

Was thinking about using StAX in a tJava module which would open the XML then read some data into an Oracle Database and update this data into the XML.

My problem is that I don't really know how to use stax in Talend taking in parameter each row from the database and updating the data this row is referring to into the XML.

How should I organize Talend's modules to develop that?
is StAX the good way to go?

The Oracle table contains

```
IDHOME  OCCADRESS   STREET              POSTALCODE  CITY
123     1           5 rue de la folie   123456      In Da City
123     2           18 rue de la joie   123457      out Da City
123     3           25  av du moulin    65882       EFDFEA
124     1           12 rue de la taver  123456      ZAER
124     2           18 rue de la joie   123456      SFFEF
125     1           46 bd le roi        39817       DIPFL
```

My xml is like :

```
<root>
  <Home>
    <homeDatas>
       <idHome>123</idHome>
        ....
        .....
    </HomeDatas>
    <peoples>
        <people>...</people>
        <people>...</people>
        <people>...</people>
        <people>...</people>
    </peoples>
    <Adresses>
        <adress>
             <OccAdress>1</OccAdress>
             <street>12 rue de la Paix</street>
             <postalCode>123456</postalCode>
             <city>Da City</city>

        </adress>
        <adress>
             <OccAdress>2</OccAdress>
             .......
        </adress>
        <adress>...</adress>
    </Adresses>
  </Home>
</root>
```

I have a first job in Talend that read the XML then extract all the adresses from a home.
Then I enrich and normalize the adresses, doesn't matter how, and put it in an oracle database.

I would like to create a job(routine) that for each line of the oracle database get the  with the IDHOME then with the OCCADRESS grab the ....  and update , ,  in this  with the data from the current line.

The main problem is that I have no idea what I could/should use to "Update" the XML but talend and StAX seemed like a good idea to do it.
I was hoping to have some help to create the tJava taking in args all the line to update + original XML file and do the job:

I actually dropped StAX and looking to use this : http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/

Thanks for your help :-D

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking here. Are you saying that you have an XML file, then you want to update a database with it? Or are you saying you want to take an XML file, enrich it with data from an Oracle database and then output an updated XML file? Also your XML file looks poorly structured. A typical structure would look something like: <homeData><idHome><people>...<person></person>...</people><address><OccAdress>...</city></address></homeData> so that an entity is grouped together

Comment: take an XML file, enrich it with data from an Oracle database and then output an updated XML file. And for the XML it s not my file I just put it in a similar shape cause it's confidential datas ;-)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question to include any attempts so far and include screenshots of any jobs you've built to try and solve this? It would be useful if you at least showed your expected output (to show how your input XML needs to be enriched). Providing more detail about the input XML would be useful (fill the elements with junk data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard Talend components to update this xml file.

Standard Xml component allows to read very big xml files.
On tFileInput xml, open the "Advanced Settings" parameters. Then select "Fast with low memory consumption (SAX)".

[image]

Then you can design a job like the following in order to merge data between your xml data source and your oracle database.

[image]

You need to extract all the data with tFileInputXml with a loop on the address node. Then you will get list of adresses joined with their idHome. Check the "getNodes" option to keep  and  in xml format like in the following screenshot.

[image]

Then you just have to make a mapping in the tMap with the keys "idHome" and "OccAdress".
Then map the output with the result of your join operation

[image]
When done, check that you get the expected result as output and connect the tAdvancedOutputXml to write your xml file.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but is it possible to target particular data to update in the tMap? In my example : updating the datas of the Adress where Home.Adresses.Adress.OccAdress= 2 and Home.HomeDatas.IdHome = 123 . Make this for each line found in the tOracleInput

Comment: Updated with 2 more screenshots. Hope you will be able to finalize the job ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like it could do it ;-) I will try this. 1 more question : Will the datas from <peoples> be reported into the final XML even if they are not in the tMAP, en not declared in the tFileInput.

Comment: The idea, here, is to create a new xml file, with the data from the InputFile, not to update the existing xml file. It means that your target file in tAdvancedOutputXml must be different from your source file. So, if you don't load the data as an input, you will not retrieve it in the output file!

Comment: :-/ To use your solution I have to enter the 235 Fields from my XML :-( Don't seems like the smartest thing to do. I will look for a solution to Update the inputfile

Comment: No, you don't need to enter the 235 Fields from your xml. How many fields are to be updated ? For the other fields, you should only keep the root node just below the <home> node and check the "getNodes" column in the tFileInputXml. How many different node do you have below <home> node ?